# C# Copy text in a textbox where focus is

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I have this problem and don't know where to start. I need to write a program that will run in WinCE, so Compact Framework will be required, and this program has to write text (a string) wherever the cursor is. I mean, if my program is running, and the cursor is in a notepad window. the text must be displayed in notepad. Or if the cursor is in another application inside a textbox (or textfield if that app was wrote in java), the text must be placed in that textbox.

I'm able to do all the other functionality the program requires, but I don't know how to do this. As far as I have read, it is done with API's. And that is all I can understand.

Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use P/Invoke keybd_event to generate keyboard entry.  The only other approach I can think of would be to put your string in the clipboard, and generate a paste key stroke.  I'm not sure every app you encounter is going to respond to CTRL+V the same.  Perhaps there's a way to trigger the paste programmatically from your app?

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "keybd_event", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
```

This should generate a silent A keystroke.

```
keybd_event((byte)Keys.A, 0, 0, 0x0004);
keybd_event((byte)Keys.A, 0, 0x0002, 0x0004);
```

Comment: I'd go with the P/Invoke because when I notice an app tampers with my clipboard, I uninstall it!

Comment: Good point.  But you can always save and restore the previous clipboard data so the user is not annoyed.  Still have to generate the CTRL+V as far as I can see there's no way to force the clipboard to paste, app has to pull.

Comment: Hi, I think this might help, how ever, can u provide a little example with the P/Invoke? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).  It's a simple way to emulate typing.

Comment: I don't think the SendKeys function is supported by Compact Framework.